# Meaning of @property (readonly) void *data; in Objective c

Tags: objective-c

I am new to iOS programming, I am preferring Swift language and I don't know Objective C. While I am wandering through some library, I got a value of type `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` in swift, that is actually a String value with utf8 encoding.

So I just looked into the corresponding objective c class and the variable is declared as 
`@property (readonly) void *data;`

So why there is void pointer and why it is converted as `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`?

Consider me as a noob in Objective c or c.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don’t understand the question. Why is there pointer to void? Well, why not? What else should be there?

Comment: Actually its a beginner question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This whole thing might be quite a lot for a beginner to understand. So let's start with ObjectiveC syntax:

Property `@property (readonly) void *data;` exposes interfaces which says there must be a method of type `- (void *)data` which means an instance method returning a `void` pointer. A void pointer being a pointer to anything.

ObjectiveC is then kind of a pure C a level deeper. I will not check exact transformation but since C has no methods this is all done with functions or even pointers to functions. So somewhere down there there should be a function (let's say the name of this class is `MyDataClass`)

```
void *myDataClass_data(MyDataClass *self) { return self->_data; } // Or whatever the implementation is
```

So nothing really interesting is going on under the hood. The whole thing just returns a position in memory without any further information of what should be there. You as a developer must know and interpret it. From C (or ObjectiveC) this is very simply. A few examples:

```
char *aString = (char *)myDataClass.data; // A pure C string. Expected to be null terminated

int *arrayOfIntegers = (int *)myDataClass.data; // An array of integers
int thirdItem = arrayOfIntegers[2];

MyDataClass *nextItem = (MyDataClass *)myDataClass.data; // A pointer to another instance
for(MyDataClass *iterator = myDataClass; iterator != nil; iterator = (MyDataClass *)iterator.data) {}
```

I hope you get the picture. The point is that C and then also ObjectiveC are very unsafe when it comes to data types. You can basically convert anything into anything however you want it and it will compile. The problem is what will happen in runtime.

When looking at Swift things get much safer and you can not just say something like `let integer: Int = myDataClass as Int`. You can force cast it and it will crash. Or you can do optional cast and it will return `nil`.

So once transitioned from C/ObjectiveC you will receive an unsafe mutable raw pointer. That means it got a position in memory witch it has no idea about what it is and how to use it. You may try to convert it to anything you want but it is **unsafe** as it will ignore all type checking. It is **mutable** probably because data it holds may be changed at any given time by any system. It is **raw** as it holds no additional information (like it's a string). And it's a **pointer** because it only points to a position in memory.

(All the snippets are symbolical to explain what goes on under the hood. Please do not take them literal)